# Where I put NotificationCenter.default.addObserver so that it can be called from any point of my framework?

Tags: ios, swift

I need add a NotificationCenter.default.addObserver in my framework project for logout. Previously I had this instruction in the appdelegate when the project was not a framework, but the frameworks don't have  this class. I tried to add this in a main uiviewcontroller, but sometimes this viewcontroller is destroyed and then the observer is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom singleton and add the "observer" there. If you need information about singleton this article is good: [what is a singleton swift](https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-singleton-and-how-to-create-one-in-swift/)

Comment: I don’t think this the proper approach, NotificationCenter.default is already a singleton

Comment: Yes, I know, but in a framework you can use a custom singleton where you can implemente a function module like a observer. This is the reason why in my answer I said "observer"